# Missing variable template argument list for template with linkedlist

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, nodes

I don't understand why in a void function in the main I have an error on the client list that is "C ++ missing variable template argument list" on each **clientList** when calling a function from linked list. The strange part is That I don't have errors in my others class except main.

```
template< class TYPE >
LinkedList<Client> clientList;

void showClientListState()
{
    cout << "Premier client: ";
    clientList.front().writeClientInfo();
    cout << "Dernier client: ";
    clientList.back().writeClientInfo();
    cout << "\n\n";
}
```

If you want to check the rest of my code:

LinkedList

```
#pragma once
#include "List.h"


template< class TYPE >
class LinkedList : public List<TYPE>        

{
public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        this->first = nullptr;
        this->last = nullptr;
        this->nbElements = 0;
    }
    ~LinkedList()
    {
        while (!isEmpty())
        {
            pop();
        }
    }

    void push(const Node<TYPE>& content)
    {
        Node<TYPE>* ptrClient = new Node<TYPE>(content);

        if (isEmpty()) {
            this->first = ptrClient;
            this->last = ptrClient;
        }
        else
        {
            last->setNext(ptrClient);
            last = ptrClient;
        }
        nbElements++;
    }
    
    void pop()
    {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw EmptyList();
        }

        Node<TYPE>* tempNodel;
        tempNodel = first;

        if (first == last)
        {
            first = last = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            first = first->getNext();
        }
        delete tempNodel;
        nbElements--;
    }


    Node<TYPE>& front()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            throw EmptyList();
        }
        return *first->getContent();
    }

    Node<TYPE>& back()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            throw EmptyList();
        }
        return *last->getContent();
    }

    
    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return (first == nullptr && last == nullptr);
    }

    int size() const
    {
        return nbElements;
    }

private:
    LinkedList(const ClientList&);
    Node<TYPE>* first;
    Node<TYPE>* last;
    int nbElements;
};
```

List interface

```
#pragma once
#pragma once
#include "EmptyList.h"
template< class TYPE >
class List
{
public:

    // Ajoute un élément à la fin de la file. 
    // Postconditions : nbElements devra être incrémenté de 1.
    virtual void push(const TYPE& content) = 0;

    // Enlève un élément au début de la file.
    // Précondition: nbElements > 0. Postcondition: nbElements sera décrémenté de 1.
    virtual void pop() = 0;

    // Retourne l’élément au début de la file.
    // Précondition: nbElements > 0.
    virtual TYPE& front() = 0;

    // Retourne l’élément à la fin de la file.
    // Précondition: nbElements > 0.
    virtual TYPE& back() = 0;

    // Retourne true si la file est vide ou false sinon.
    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

    // Retourne le nombre d’éléments dans la file.
    virtual int size() const = 0;

};
```

node class

```
#pragma once
template< class TYPE >
class Node
{
public:
    Node(const TYPE& content)
    {
        setContent(content);
        setNext(nullptr);
    }

    ~Node()
    {
        delete content;
    }

    Node* getNext()
    {
        return this->next;
    }

    void setNext(Node* next)
    {
        this->next = next;
    }

    //Retourne le contenu de cet élément.
    TYPE* getContent()
    {
        return this->content;
    }

    //Change la contenu de cet élément.
    void setContent(const TYPE& content)
    {
        this->content = new TYPE(content);
    }

private:
    Node* next = nullptr;

    TYPE* content = nullptr;
};
```

And The Main that I can't touch except create linked list from template

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vld.h>
#include "LinkedList.hpp"
#include "Client.h"

using namespace std;

LinkedList<Client> clientList;

template< class TYPE >
void showClientListState()
{
   cout << "Premier client: ";
   clientList.front().writeClientInfo();
   cout << "Dernier client: ";
   clientList.back().writeClientInfo();
   cout << "\n\n";
}

template< class TYPE >
void manageClientAdd(const Client& client)
{
   cout << "Ajout d'un client\n";
   clientList.push(client);
   showClientListState();
}
template< class TYPE >
void manageClientRemove()
{
   cout << "Retrait d'un client\n";

   if (clientList.isEmpty())
   {
       cout << "La liste était déja vide\n\n";
       return;
   }

   clientList.pop();

   if (clientList.isEmpty())
       cout << "La liste est maintenant vide\n\n";
   else
       showClientListState();
}
template< class TYPE >
void main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr-CA");
   cout << "\nUtilisation de la liste de clients.\n\n";
   
   Client client1(1, "Télesphore", "LeGamer");
   Client client2(2, "Herménégide", "LaVedette");
   Client client3(3, "Leopoldine", "LaSportive");
   


   Client client4(4, "Amidala", "LaPrincesse");

   manageClientAdd(client1);
   manageClientAdd(client2);
   manageClientAdd(client3);
   manageClientAdd(client4);

   for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
       manageClientRemove();

   system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: What is `Client`? You omitted its declaration.

Comment: *"on each **clientList**"* -- I'm guessing that what you wrote is not what you mean. You meant "on each **line using** `clientList`", didn't you? However, since `clientList` is a template, "each clientList" is closer to meaning "each **instantiation of** `clientList`". You probably did not intend for `clientList` to be a template, which shows how important language precision is. You should write what you mean, and not use lazy phrasings with the hope that the reader is willing to fill in the missing words and will fill in the intended words.

Comment: Client should not be touched

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"Client should not be touched"*. It should not be touched by you even though your code uses `Client`?

Comment: @JaMiT client is a proprety given by my teacher that world perfectly, but I don't have to touch it because it isn't part of what my task is.

Comment: *"client is a proprety"* -- no, `Client` is a type, not a property. In any event, I think you meant "the `Client` ***implementation*** should not be touched. More precisely, the implementation should not be touched *for your assignment*. That does not mean you cannot include a definition (or at least a declaration) in this question, and it does not mean you cannot simplify the definition *for this question*, as part of your **[mre]**.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
template<class TYPE>
LinkedList<Client> clientList;
```

you want to write

```
LinkedList<Client> clientList;
```

That is, remove the `template<class TYPE>` before the declaration of `clientList`. You don't want `clientList` to be a new [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template), you want it to be one variable that happens to have a type that's an instance of a template.

Comment: Where do you see it the template<class TYPE>
LinkedList<Client> clientList;

Comment: @NicolasPellerin *"Where do you see it the template<class TYPE> LinkedList<Client> clientList;"* -- uh, first two lines of your first code block? It's kind of hard to miss if you're reading the code.

Comment: @NicolasPellerin That's a separate issue, caused by the fact that `LinkedList` doesn't define a member function that overrides `void push(const TYPE& content)`. Note that `LinkedList::push(const Node<TYPE>&)` is a _different_ function (the signatures don't match). You'd get a more informative compiler error about this is you use the [override specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) on `LinkedList::push`

Comment: It doesn't work can you read the new version? I really don't know were are my problems.

Comment: Are you there Brian?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Brians answer, in your "Main" code, remove all "template< class TYPE >"s.

Thus:

```
template< class TYPE >
void showClientListState()
{
...
```

must be

```
void showClientListState()
{
...
```

and the same for

```
template< class TYPE >
void manageClientAdd(const Client& client)
{
...
```

```
template< class TYPE >
void manageClientRemove()
{
```

```
template< class TYPE >
void main()
{
```

None of those functions should or can depend on any template parameter. The only thing in your code depending on a template parameter is `LinkedList` directly. But `LinkedList<Client>` ALSO does not depend on a template parameter because you fully specified its type using `Client`.

Thus, for `showClientListState` change:

```
template< class TYPE >
LinkedList<Client> clientList;

void showClientListState()
{
```

into

```
#include "Client.h"

LinkedList<Client> clientList;

void showClientListState()
{
```

Those are just the obvious errors. For a full answer, you must produce the entire problem. But don't just upload more code. Produce a **minimally reproducible example**. This is important to ask questions in general.

Comment: Sorry but I am not really good at template. It is my first exercice.

Comment: But now, it is showing that my expression needs a type which is client but I don't know what I do wrong

Comment: You have to post the exact error message from your compiler and the lines of source code involved  here to get more help.